# When using telnet get request on the website weer.nl - I get a 301 error that I can't fix

Tags: http, get, telnet, http-status-code-301

[Link to photo of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH5g8.png)

I am trying to get the header of from the webpage www.weer.nl. However it only returns a 301 Moved Permanently error and does not print any header to terminal.

How can I fix this?

The link shows when I enter into terminal - 
         telnet weer.nl 80
         HEAD / HTTP/1.1
         Host: weer.nl

it what is circled is what is outputted back.

[2nd Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcZfj.png)

Comment: Please review [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then don't post images of text, copy-paste the text *as text* into your question body instead.

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Why can't you add more details to this question.

Comment: I have tried to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 301 Moved Permanently error

Moved Permanently is **not** an error.

> does not print any header to terminal

Wrong. Your screenshot clearly shows it outputting 6 headers: Including the `Location` header which tells you the URL that it has moved to and which you should be requesting.

Comment: Ah alright thanks for the response. Why is the content length 0 then? When I use a get method, it also outputs a content length of 0.

Comment: @dragonslayer7 — Because the response body has no content in it. It is using only the HTTP headers to tell you where it has moved to.

Comment: Okay yes understand that - I'm trying to find a way to show contents of this page though and can't find a way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @dragonslayer7 — Request the URL the redirect is telling you to request.

Comment: That's exactly what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @dragonslayer7 — The same way as you requested `http://weer.nl/` only with the new URL.

Comment: Okay great I've tried. Thanks a lot for the help. I have attached another photo '2nd Attempt' however it does not look correct. Is this a problem with the web page or something I have coded?

Comment: @dragonslayer7 — The hostname should not include the URL scheme